# Tkinter font style

Tags: fonts, tkinter

I'm trying to design an interface, and I came across this problem.

When I create text in the center of the screen with the font style "bold", everything works fine.

```
cnvs.create_text(400,400,text="Test", font=('Helvetica Neue',50,'bold'),fill="white",anchor='c')
```

But, when I try to make it light or ultralight, it dosn't work, even though I have those types installed.

```
cnvs.create_text(400,400,text="Test", font=('Helvetica Neue',50,'light'),fill="white",anchor='c')
```

Any one know why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because "light" isn't a valid option. The only valid options for the font style are "normal", "bold", "roman", "italic", "underline" and "overstrike".

Comment: Is there any possible workaround for this. I'm trying to build a modern looking application, and the normal fonts dont achieve the look I want.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to work around this -- "light" is simply not an attribute of a font. Maybe you're using the wrong font family. Have you tried "Helvetica Neue Light" as the font family?